# Normalization issue: Additional accuracy field for date (MySQL database)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, normalization

I need to store dates with different accuracies in a MySQL database.

For example, a book publication date may be known up to the specific day (14.05.2007), up to the month (May, 2007), or only up to the year (2007). Same for the birthdate, or the death date of the author.

Solution #1: A separate Date table with a date field and a precision (day/month/year) field as well. In the above example, the Book.PublicationDate and the Author.BirthDate fields will reference the Date table.

Solution #2: Don't add a separate Date table, just add a date precision field wherever there is a date (at the Book and Author tables in the example)

Sol. #1 seems a little awkward, but gives a more normalized database. #2 is certainly simpler and more natural. I am a little normalization-obsessed, so I would vote for #1. What do you think?

Thank you!

Comment: What will you be doing with the dates?  From the perspective of just storing the data, the two are very similar.  It is how the data gets used that might push in one direction or another.

Comment: Store as date. Then use precision as necessary when manipulating those dates.

Comment: I will just store the dates and never modify them. Querying by book publication date or author birthdate is possible. If these do have a precision, it makes everything complicated.

I am actually right now thinking that maybe I need to store just the year for the dates, and thus simplify everything.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add another table for Dates that is just taking normalization too far.
See http://joinfu.com/presentations/dqm/legend_drunken_query_master.pdf page 16

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying answer: I actually DON'T need to store more accurate data than the year, so that's what I will do.

More complicated answer: In case more accurate data is needed, solution #2 is indeed over-normalizing. It can though make sense if we want to have a date used by many different entities and/or entity instances appear just once in the database.